# Readline() reads only first line

Tags: java

I need to read a text file and split using a common text in the lines, and print a part of the split text. This works fine but only does this for the first line in the text. 
However, if I print lines without the split part, it prints correctly. Please what am I doing wrong?

File sample: (I want to split by "words")

Line 1 This text is of length: 7 words. I need to learn how to program.

Line 2 Now we have text of length: 3 words. No matter what the words are, I must program

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
//Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String line = null;
ArrayList<String> txt1 = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] pair = line.split("words");
    txt1.add(pair[1]);
    System.out.println(txt1);
    //System.out.println(line);
}

br.close();
```

Comment: You may have to show us a sample of your file.

Comment: If you find an answer useful, you can click the up-arrow. If one of them answers your question, you can click the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following unit test simulating the input of a file via a StringInputStream:

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException
{
    String fileContent = "This text is of length: 7 words.\r\nI need to learn how to program and one day.";
    StringInputStream stream = new StringInputStream(fileContent);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<String> txt1 = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] pair = line.split("words");
        txt1.add(pair[1]);
        System.out.println(txt1);
        //System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

The first line will be split into

```
"This text is of length: 7 " and
"."
```

Since you put item [1] into the array list, it'll just contain a single dot.

The second line will be split into

```
"I need to learn how to program and one day."
```

only. There is no second item, so accessing [1] results in a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.